# Update map skobbler process

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I try to figure out how to update map with Skobbler SKMaps framework, using the v2.5.1 with iOS swift.

As suggested here : http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec33, I correctly configured my mapsVersioningManager delegate in AppDelegate.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let initSettings: SKMapsInitSettings = SKMapsInitSettings()
    
    SKMapsService.sharedInstance().initializeSKMaps(withAPIKey: API_KEY, settings: initSettings)
    SKMapsService.sharedInstance().mapsVersioningManager.delegate = self
    return true
}
```

So in my log, I have this lines :

```
"Map version file download finished."
"current map version : 20150413"
```

I know there is a new map version file available which is 20160426. But it is not detected, and the protocol detectedNewAvailableMapVersion is not triggered.

I also tried to put this line right after setting the mapsVersioningManager delegate :

```
SKMapsService.sharedInstance().mapsVersioningManager.update(toVersion: "20160426")
```

But map version is still 20150413.

Then in MAPJSONParser Model class, I modified code like this

```
SKMapsService.sharedInstance().packagesManager.mapsJSONURL(forVersion: "20160426")
```

Still nothing.

In a desperate way, I also tried to add a new line in SKMaps.bundle a file found in PreInstalledMaps "`version3_public_sdk_iOS_2_5_1.txt`"

> 20160426 9874 http://tor.skobbler.net RSngx 20_5 NBngx 20_5
>
> http://traffic.skobbler.net/Traffic/2.0/NgTraffic/
>
> http://traffic.skobbler.net/Traffic/2.0/NgIncidents/

I hope you could help me :) !

Comment: P.S. : SKMapsService.sharedInstance().mapsVersioningManager.availableMapVersions returns an array of available versions and 20150413 is the latest.
P.S.2 : when I uninstall the app and reinstall, the last version 20160426 is detected ! Probably because it updates the SKMaps.bundle. But I can't ask my users to uninstall my app ....

Answer (score 0):

Until I have a better answer, I found a workaround that may help someone.  So here it is :

Prebundle a map with newest version into your app. This will cause the SKMapVersioningManager to change its currentMapVersion to the prebundled map version one. Then all new maps are downloaded with newest version.

Comment: Hi, i have the same issue. Could you let me know how to prebundle a map version? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find it here : https://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios in Map Packages section